# Site install fails with Aegir

Tags: aegir

I've been using Aegir to install Atrium sites without a hitch. Users self register through Aegir to spawn their own open atrium sites. Today I noticed new atrium sites failed to install. A week ago this worked fine and as far as I know nothing has been changed with core content/modules. I did some comparisons in looking at the task log between the failed install and a successful install (from a week ago). The simplexml load and "Could not download project status information" is weird. Here's what I gathered so far. Task install log looks identical until near the end. The failed install shows the following after "downloading release history…":

```
Downloading release history from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/6.x
simplexml_load_file(): 6.x:2: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute http-e pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
simplexml_load_file(): ^ pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): 6.x:2: parser error : attributes construct error pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
simplexml_load_file(): ^ pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): 6.x:2: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag meta line 2 pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
simplexml_load_file(): ^ pm.drush.inc:2103
simplexml_load_file(): 6.x:12: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 11 and body pm.drush.inc:2103
```

This goes on for several more lines - finally ending in the following error:

```
Could not download project status information from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/6.x
```

This compares to This compares to the successful site task install log here:

```
Downloading project drupal to /tmp/drush_tmp_1368706259 ...
Downloading drupal-6.28.tar.gz was successful.
Md5 checksum of drupal-6.28.tar.gz verified.
Verifying signature for svn version control engine.
Verifying signature for bzr version control engine.
Project drupal (6.28) downloaded to /var/www/vhosts/site.com/platforms/atrium-1.0/drupal-6.28.
Project drupal contains: - 1 profile: default - 6 themes: pushbutton, min... (Expand)
```

The diff analysis looks similar again for many more lines, then shows the following error for the failed install log:

```
WD form: Illegal choice 5 in Roles allowed to use this profile element.
WD form: Illegal choice 6 in Roles allowed to use this profile element.
```

The rest of the task log for the failed install shows typical Aegir behavior of dropping the database and deleting directory.Searching through my general site logs, or when I run cron, I get

"Unable to fetch any information about available new releases and updates."
I also get that error when I try to manually run cron 
Also a few other things like:

```
Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in theme_render_template() (line 1079 of/var/www/vhosts/site.com/hostmaster-6.x-1.4/includes/theme.inc).

An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

The "unable to fetch information about new releases..." error is weird and similar to the Aegir error on the failed install task log. 
Unfortunately I don't know where to start. I'm wondering if this is a write permissions issue with drush, or php version issue. It;s starnge that it's happened suddenly, so maybe Aegir changed something on the fly. Don't know... Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: No problem now. I seem to have had a hard coded ip address inside my host file which drush couldnt download the xml update.

Answer (score 0):

This line says it all:
    Could not download project status information from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/6.x

Probably not a problem you or Aegir could do anything about. Just an Internet hickup.